# iOS SpriteKit Bounciness

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have two nodes in my scene. The first node is a ball at the top of my view. The second node is a rectangle at the bottom of my view to stop the ball from dropping out of view. I am wanting this ball to have NO bounciness at all. I am wanting it to just completely stop when it hits the rectangle. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
SKSpriteNode *rectangle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 50)];

    bottom.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, 0);
    bottom.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(rectangle, bottom.size.height)];
    bottom.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    [self addChild:bottom];



SKSpriteNode *ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball"];
ball.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y);
ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius: 5];
ball.physicsBody.restitution = 0;

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, [self randomX], [self randomY]);

SKAction *move = [SKAction followPath:path asOffset:YES orientToPath:NO duration:3.0];


[ball runAction:move];

[self addChild: ball];
```

Why is is still bouncing off the rectangle?

Comment: You are using SKAction to move the ball, this will completely bypass physics. You need to use applyForce/applyImpulse on the physicsBody to move it, so that it is only influenced by physics forces, not by moving the graphics which drags the body behind it, ignoring collisions and what not (actions for instance don't stop moving and won't move to a new direction if the physics body collides). Then you'd have to implement the contact event so that you can set the velocity of the ball to 0,0 when it hits the rectangle.

Comment: I really need to be able to use SKAction though because I need it to travel along the path. Any ideas?

Comment: When the ball hit the rectangle just call [ball removeAllActions];

Comment: That didn't work Julio. LearnCocos2D, can you show me some code for applying force/impulses. It does nothing when I enter in the dx/dy values.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you should in more cases than not be working with frameworks like they expects you to, hacks just end up with weird quirks like the one you encountered. In this case, as @LearnCocos2D said, you should probably be using `[ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:(CGVEctor)]` if you need the ball to move along a specific path but still maintain a dynamic physicsBody. If you then set the restitution to 0, it will not bounce. I promise.

Read up on vectors and vector maths if you need the ball to follow a specific path (it's knowledge that is good to have anyways when working with physics). I've found [this](http://openframeworks.cc/tutorials/maths/001_vector_maths.html) to be a good resource for that. It's for openFrameworks, hence C++, but the concept remains the same.

And if you still really need to use a `CGPath`, then I think you should tell us a bit more specific about what you need to accomplish. There might be a better solution, or maybe we should file a bug to Apple. Sprite-Kit is still fairly young, I have myself encounter problems I believe to be bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation indicates that the value of the "restitution" property of SKPHysicsBody is "how much energy the physics body loses when it bounces off another object." ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/restitution)). By setting the restitution to zero, you make the ball as bouncy as possible - it loses 0 energy. If you set the restitution to 1 - loses all energy - it should stop.